# Best way for Excel workbooks to share VBA functions

Tags: vba, excel, version-control

**I seek advice on how to manage userdefined VBA-functions that are used in several workbooks:**

**Background:**
Over time i have created several Excel workbooks (wbs), each with a slightly different purpose, that are ultimately based on a library of my userdefined functions and class modules (From now on: **library**). The "master"-versions of the wbs are revision-controlled. The wbs are used by several people.

However, I do not use an addin for the **library**, and hence the modules and class modules are actually locally present in each wb's specific VBA project. This makes it a nightmare when doing either expansions or corrections, as I have to revisit and implement said alterations in each wb.

Furthermore, in each wb there are unique functions, understood such that those are not intended to be shared. Those functions, however, might utilize the **library**-functions.

**Main-Question**: How should one manage vba functions across several workbooks shared by several users?

**My considerations/Sub questions**:

- Should I convert the **library** to a true addin and discard the local copies in each wb?
- How do I tell the users that the add-in is required upon getting a copy of the maser-version?
- How does one cope with legacy/local versions/branches that are spread among the users? Both current legacy copys and future legacy copies that might be used for reccuring tasks?
- Where should such an addin-in be stored (in a shared folder or something)?
- Would it be considered "bad practice" to force load the add-in using the `workbook_open`sub?

Any advice or guidance in best practice is appreciated.

**Edit**: I have tried to highlight the main question, please consider the sub questions as my own thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Please publich 1 (specific) question per post... they all shall be on-topic for SO currently your questions don't seem to fill that criteria... first go through the tour

Comment: Hi @B001ᛦ As I see my posted questions they are ultimately elaborations of one grand question: how should Excel workbooks share vba functions? In general the forum rules are to be as specific as possible, and as such the  (sub)-questions are an attempt at exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until recently, I had several add-ins that lived on a shared drive. I had the users install the add-in using File - Options - Addins and wrote up the instructions to do it. The copy on the shared drive was read-only. For changes, I would code and test on the dev copy on my machine, then deploy it to the shared drive. The next time the user started Excel, the changes would be there.

Then we wanted more people to have the addins and not all of them had access to this shared drive. Also, people complained when they were off the network that it still tried to connect to the addins. So we went a different route.

We used a program called PDQ Deploy to put the addins in everyone's addins directory, so they had a local copy. We also deployed a script that copied the files from a company-wide shared drive to their addins directory. If they weren't connected to the nextwork, the script would fail silently. Finally, we used group policy to 1) create the registry entries to install the addins and 2) create a scheduled task that kicked off the script every night. Updating every day is overkill, but the files are only a few kbs, so we went with it.

Now I can deploy new versions to the company-wide shared drive and everyone will have the changes the next day (or the day after they're back on the network).

Comment: I have looked into this, and that might work. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I put my vba stuff on the "personal" workbook (Windows menu : Unhide...) and whatever workbook I am using I can use them from there.

You do have to make sure about knowing which one is acrtive though...

Comment: I do that as well for my own personal macros, functions and such. However, the workbooks in question are intended to be shared and used by others.

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider an install script that adds a specific sheet (give it a special name ...) to the personal workbook on each of the relevant machines - you could ask the user to run each time there is an update for example

Comment: That is an interesting approach! Do you have any experience with this compared to addins?